# ElasticSearch: How to search for documents by list of subelements

Tags: elasticsearch

How should my elasticsearch search-queries look like if i need to select only those elements, that have

1. At least one subelement with result: "FAILURE"
2. None subelement with "FAILURE"
3. Only elements with values "OK"

Example of element document

```
{
    "name": "bla",
    "id": "11234",
    "subelements_count": "3",
    "subelement": [
                {"id": "221", "name": "Sub1", "result": "OK" },
               ....
                {"id": "222", "name": "Sub2", "result": "FAILURE" }
    ]
}
```

Bonus question: Can i have a searchquery that selects only elements where field subelements_count matches distinct number of different id's present in the subelement list?

Comment: Can you share the queries that you've tried/tested? and also the mapping.

Comment: I didn't  do any tests so far, because the question is important to understand Elastic Search capabilities at all. If we are going to use it that way...

Comment: It is safe to say that Elasticsearch possess the capabilities that you're looking for.

Comment: @ChandraPraneethN maybe you can provide some hints to design and queries parst is for example Inner hits or field collaapsing to use?